# The Google Map doesn't appear working with Ionic and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

The Google Map doesn't appear.  I work with Ionic and AngularJS and I use the Geolocation plugin.

This is my routing for the app:

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider
    .state('menu.rServation', {
    url: '/Réservation',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/rServation.html',
        controller: 'rServationCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu.voiture', {
    url: '/Voiture',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/voiture.html',
        controller: 'voitureCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu.paramTres', {
    url: '/Paramètres',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/paramTres.html',
        controller: 'paramTresCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('menu.LocationMap', {
    url: '/Location',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/Locationmap.html',
        controller: 'LocationMapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('menu.LocationMMap', {
    url: '/Locationn',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/LocationMMap.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('menu.login', {
    url: '/Login',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu', {
    url: '/side-menu21',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    abstract:true
  })

  .state('menu.detailsVoiture', {
    url: '/Voiture/:Id',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detailsVoiture.html',
        controller: 'voitureCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu.conexion', {
    url: '/Conexion',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/conexion.html',
        controller: 'conexionCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('menu.detailsPreReservation',{
    url: '/DetailsPreReservation',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detailsPreReservation.html',
        controller: 'detailsPreReservationCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('menu.profile',{
    url: '/profile',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profil.html',
        controller: 'profilCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/side-menu21/Réservation')

});
```

and this is mu controller

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  }, function(error){
    console.log("Could not get location");
  });
})
```

and this my view:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and this my menu.html for side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left" id="side-menu21">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
            <div class="title">Menu</div>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.rServation" menu-close=""  >
                <i class="icon ion-home balanced ">Réservation</i>                            
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.voiture" menu-close=""  >
                 <i class="icon ion-model-s balanced">Voitures</i> 
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.paramTres" menu-close="" >
                 <i class="icon ion-android-settings balanced">Paramètres</i> 
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.LocationMap" menu-close="" >
                 <i class="icon ion-map balanced">Location Agence</i> 
                </ion-item>
                  <ion-item ui-sref="menu.LocationMMap" menu-close="" >
                 <i class="icon ion-map balanced">Locationn Agence</i> 
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ui-sref="menu.login" menu-close="" >
                <i class="icon ion-log-in balanced">Login</i> 
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

This is an image for the template and no error

[image: Image of template]

Comment: Are you setting a height of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the height for the container:

```
<style>
#map {
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
```